# Stack Smashing Error While Working with CStrings

Tags: c++, stack-smash

I am working on a small project and I am absolutely stuck. The purpose of the function I'm working on is to rearrange and change a Cstring based on a few preset rules. Where my issue lies is within the second portion of my swapping algorithm I came up with.

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  if(sentence[i] == SPACE)
  {
    space++;
    spacePlace[counter] = i;
    counter++;
  }
}
for(int i = 0; i < space; i++)
{
  if(i == 0)
  {
    count2 = 0;
    for(int h = 0; h < 20; h++)
    {
      temp1[h] = NUL;
      temp2[h] = NUL;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < spacePlace[0]; j++)
      temp1[j] = sentence[j];
    for(int m = spacePlace[0]; m < spacePlace[1]; m++)
    {
      temp2[count2] = sentence[m];
      count2++;
    }
.
. 
.
```

the first for loops executes perfectly and the output is great, but the second for loop always messes up and ends up sending me a stack smashing error. For more reference, sentence is a cstring passed to the function, and temp1 and temp2 are also cstrings. Any help or points in the right direction would be a godsend. Thanks!

Comment: ...do you have a constant `ZERO` and `ONE`?

Comment: yes in my header file i have ZERO = 0 and ONE = 1. the outline for the project requires literally everything to be constants and they are defined as such.

Comment: That is unfortunate. But about the question, you should provide a [MCVE]. The present snippet doesn't seem to be sufficient to identify the problem.

Comment: I feel bad for you if you have to do `#define ZERO 0`.

Comment: You're most likely writing outside the bounds of a local array. Add some bounds-checking.

Comment: That's just the thing though. Above it in the code I have bound checking and clear the contents of whatever was in the array before. The big issue im getting is that an input of say "You" passes perfectly fine through the first for loop and to temp1, but if i pass the same "you" or something like "if" to it, it will take it but also pin on whatever the contents of temp1 are and some random characters.

Comment: Re your edit: in `for(int h = 0; h < 20; h++)`, `20` is a "magic number", but `0` isn't.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I've tried to use GDB but got confused and couldn't tell where it was going wrong

Comment: @dirtydan There is no bounds checking on any of your array assignments.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about that then? The max size of each temp array is hard capped to be 20. It seems like its still within the bounds but there's a good chance I'm missing something simple. I've been up all night doing this thing.

Comment: What is the value of `spacePlace[0]` ? If it is more than 19 then it would try to write to memory outside of temp1.

Comment: Can count2 exceed 19? If that is the case then again it would be outside of temp2.

Comment: spacePlace[0] is 3, and spacePlace[1] is 6. the difference between each of the spacePlace values is designed to be less than 20. Well, in theory. Idk why this is making me struggle so hard

Comment: you never know, ZERO might be 42 in some cases, slippery things these numbers